# Using user-selected input as function parameter in shiny?

Tags: r, parameters, shiny

Suppose I have in my shiny ui.R an input:

```
selectInput("choice","Select Values",choices=c('a','b','c',FALSE),
            selected="FALSE")
```

And I want to use this input as a parameter to a function in server.R. The default value for this parameter is `FALSE`, but can take in character values. I want to set it so that, for example, if the user select `'a'`, the value `'a'` would be passed on to the parameter in the function, and if the user select `'FALSE'`, the default value of `FALSE` is passed on to the parameter.

The way I tried to do this is by:

```
choice <- ifelse(input$choice=='FALSE',FALSE,input$choice)
```

and then use it in the function:

```
sample_func(param=choice)
```

However, this gives me an error `"param has the wrong format"`. The error is the result of `choice` not being a character value or `FALSE`.

What might be the reason for this?

Comment: This works for me, is it a problem with how `sample_func` handles its input?

Comment: hm okay I had set multiple = T in my program for selectInput, if I delete that it seems to work. How does the multiple argument affect this when I have not selected multiple inputs?

Comment: `ifelse` is tricky with vectors, you will get one value back per comparison

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is:

`choice <- ifelse(input$choice=='FALSE',FALSE,input$choice)`

This must be written in a reactive context as it depends on user input. So you have to wrap your `ifelse(...)` part in `reactive()`. Of course I don't know if you had done so already since you didn't post the entire code and I assume you just wrote that code without the wrapping of `reactive()`.

Another thing concerning this same line is not really a bug, but a habit. It's a bad idea to use `choice` again. The point is, it already existed as in `input$choice` and now you assign it to a reactive value of the same name. That could be confusing if you have a complex and long code.

So, I would suggest something like this below.

`fun_choice <- reactive(ifelse(input$choice=='FALSE',FALSE,input$choice))`

The next problem is in:

`sample_func(param=fun_choice)  ## I changed the argument name to fun_choice`

If you had treated `fun_choice` as reactive, That should be replaced by `fun_choice()`. Also, that would mean that this function result should also be in reactive context. So the line should become:

`variable_name <- reactive( sample_func(param=fun_choice()) )`

Of course, it could be wrapped in `observe` if what you want is the side effect and some other things but not the function return.

Hope this help.

One last thing, if `fun_choice` is of no other use elsewhere but just passing into `sample_func`, I would suggest you put them in one `reactive()`. i.e.

```
variable_name <- reactive({
  fun_choice <- ifelse(input$choice == 'FALSE', FALSE, input$choice)
  sample_func(param = fun_choice)
})
```

Note that in this method, `fun_choice`, within the same `reactive()`, need not be expressed as `fun_choice()`, but simply `fun_choice`.